# Simple SQL query issue in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a really strange problem.

I simply want to select all posts that feature in two given categories.

Heres my SQL:

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 83  
   AND   wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 84
```

This should return one result but it doesnt return anything.

If I comment out:

```
*wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 83*
```

The post im looking for is returned.

If I comment out:

```
*wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 84*
```

Again, the post is returned.

Why then,when both of these conditions are included, nothing is returned?

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all posts that have both those `term_taxonomy_id`'s associated with them you can use:

```
SELECT  p.ID 
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r
  ON p.ID = r.object_id
WHERE  r.term_taxonomy_id IN (83, 84)
GROUP BY p.ID 
HAVING count(distinct r.term_taxonomy_id) =2
```

This will return all records that have both taxonomy terms.

Your query will not work because the `term_taxonomy_id` cannot have two values at the same time. You can change your query to use `OR` instead of `AND` or you can use the version I provided.

Answer (score 2):

The `wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` couldn't be `=83` and `=84` in the same time.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT  
  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (83 , 48);
```

OR

```
...
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 83  
   OR wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 84;
```

But, I think you are looking for those posts that have both `term_taxonomy_id`' ids 83, 84 in the same time, and in this case , you are looking for the [*relation division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/); here is one way to do so:

```
SELECT  
  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT *
   FROM wp_term_relationships
   WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id
                       FROM  wp_term_relationships
                       WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (83 , 48);
                       GROUP BY objecT_id
                       HAVING COUNT(term_taxonomy_id ) = 2)
)  t ON wp_posts.ID = t.object_id;
```

**Or:** Directly, without `JOIN`. Like so:

```
SELECT  
  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT object_id
    FROM  wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (83 , 48);
    GROUP BY objecT_id
    HAVING COUNT(term_taxonomy_id ) = 2
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would not work for me because I need to return all posts that feature in both categories. Using IN (83,84) would return posts that may only feature in one category

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results to show posts that are in both categories, you need to get both results and compare them:

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM   (
        SELECT  wp_posts.ID 
        FROM wp_posts 
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
        WHERE  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 83
        ) a
        INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT  wp_posts.ID 
                    FROM wp_posts 
                    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
                    WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 84
                    ) b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Somewhat more complicated than just changing AND to OR

Comment: Depends if he wants results that match both (as in my example), or results that match either - in which case the or is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to use "OR" rather than "AND". My guess is that you're not looking for the post where the taxonomy_id is BOTH 83 and 84, but where it's one of the two?

Answer (score 0):

Your query says :

```
WHERE  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 83  
AND    wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  = 84
```

This will return nothing, I suspect you should change AND to OR